# Mean of overcooking time

Tags: probability, random-variables, stopping-times

This question came up this week when I had to put my rice in the microwave for a third time.

Suppose the perfect cooking time for a meal is given by a random variable $X$ with values in seconds. Now suppose a quick check allows to determine if the food is :

1. Uncooked,
2. Perfectly cooked,
3. Overcooked.

What is the **estimated overcooking time in seconds** if one uses the following technique :

Start by cooking for $T$ seconds, then

a) Check food state.

b) If food if perfectly cooked or overcooked, stop.

c) If food is uncooked, double the last $T$ used.

An answer could also hint for a better technique or optimize the choice of $T$.

EDIT : As suggested bellow, let us assume that $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$.

Comment: A harder problem would suppose that each time one checks the food, one looses $L$ seconds of cooking. Or $p$ percents of cooking.

Comment: This question is not really answerable without a prior distribution of $X$ (there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: Still one could express the answer in terms of P(X=k)? Or answer for common distributions.

Comment: The overcooking time is given by various formulas equivalent to $$T\mathbf 1_{X=0}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(nT-X)\mathbf 1_{(n-1)T<X\leqslant nT}$$

Comment: To judge whether cooked or not, you need an acceptable range of error, say a percentage within the perfect cooking time within which the rice is considered perfect - say $+-5\%$ as probabiltiy of being exactly right is zero.

Comment: Can you clarify the algorithm?  Are you checking every $T$ seconds, or are you doubling the cooking interval sizes $\{T, 2T, 4T, 8T, ...\}$, or is the first cook interval $T$ and the remaining ones $2T$? [In other words, does "cook for $2T$ seconds" mean "cook for $2T$ more seconds" or "cook for $T$ more seconds"?]

Comment: I second Michael's question in the comment above. It is not clear what the checking algorithm is. Also in your edit you assume **T** to be normally distributed. Do you mean **X**?

Comment: I made the suggested changes.

Comment: I thought $X$ was a discrete r.v., but now it says $X$ is Normal, and remember Normal r.v.'s are supported on the whole real line.  In any case, a Normal seems inappropriate because the cooking time can't be negative.  Maybe logNormal would be a good place to start.

Comment: Quite apart from any mathematical considerations, I have good luck putting my rice in an all-glass container (not even the lid is plastic); the glass lid vents just enough to steam the rice properly.

Comment: Why would one _double_ the cooking time if, on checking, it is not yet cooked? What is the cost of checking more often? What are the costs of overcooking (throw it out?) and undercooking (salmonella?).  Why would you eat food from a microwave? :)

Comment: Let's say that checking is unpleasant and overcooking is too. So one would like to minimise the number of checks and the overcooking time. I fixed the research algorithm so we only have to minimize the overcooking time.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but it is too long to fit in the comments. (No reference here to a similar sentence by a chap named Fermat.)

Let $\{ t_n \}_{n=1}^N$ be the sequence of times at which you plan to stop and check, where $N$ may be finite or infinite. In your question, for instance, this is defined recursively as $a_1 = T$ and $a_n = a_{n-1} + T$.

(Incidentally, for well-behaved distributions, I'd expect that it is better to have $a_n - a_{n-1}$ decreasing, because the longer you have cooked, the higher the risk of overcooking.)

Let $X$ the "perfect time". If $X \le a_1$, you stop cooking at $a_1$: this occurs with probability $P(X \le a_1)$ and gives you an expected overcooking time $E(a_1-X|X\le a_1)$. If If $a_{n-1} < X \le a_n$, you stop cooking at $a_n$: this occurs with probability $P(a_{n-1} < X \le a_n)$ and gives you an expected overcooking time $E(a_n-X|a_{n-1}<X \le a_n)$.

Define $a_0=0$ for convenience. Adding up across all cases, the formula for the expected overcooking is
$$\sum_{n=1}^N P(a_{n-1} < X \le a_n) E(a_n-X|a_{n-1}<X \le a_n)$$

For instance, if $X$ is uniformly distributed between 0 and 100 and we take $T=1$ in your checking schedule and thus $N=100$, we find
$$\sum_{n=1}^N P(a_{n-1} < X \le a_n) E(a_n-X|a_{n-1}<X \le a_n) = \\ \sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{\left(n - (n-1) \right)}{100} E(n-X|n-1<X \le n) = \\ \sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{1}{100} E(n-X|n-1<X \le n) = \\ \sum_{n=1}^{100} \frac{1}{100} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the remainder of $\frac{\mathbb{E} X}{T}.$  This is essentially the overshoot that you expect based on the step length $T$.  In particular, if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then this would be the remainder of $\frac{\mu}{T}.$ If $X$ is a discrete r.v. with probabilities $p_1, \dots, p_n$, then the expected overcooking time is the remainder of $\frac{\sum_n p_n x_n}{T}.$
The choices of $T$ that lead to zero expected overcooking time are contained in the set $\{\frac{\mathbb{E} X}{  k }\mid k \in \mathbb{N} \}.$

Something interesting is that no matter what we choose for $T$, even if the expected overcooking time is zero, the wait time will still have a variance of $\mathbb{E}(kT-X)^2, $ where $k = \text{argmin} \{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid kT \ge X\}$.  In particular, when $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2),$
$$
\mathbb{E}(kT-X)^2 = T^2 \mathbb{E} k^2 - 2T \mathbb{E} kX + \sigma^2.
$$
This is where I will leave my answer, mostly because I don't know what the distribution of $k$ should be.  The formula for variance that I found does shed some light on the problem -- evidently the variance is quadratic in $T$.  In other words, the more often we check, the less variance we expect in our wait time at the expense of opening and closing the microwave door many times.